# Redux thunk, initialize ingredients with axios, question

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

Hey guys i really want to undestand something. I do a react js course and i couldn't undestand a part where we initialized the burger Ingredients from a database using redux thunk.

My question is, HOW is setIngredients function called, when i don't call it anywhere? Because when i call in the componentDidMount the setIngredients, it won't work, but if i call initIngredients, it will.
Is it called in the initIngredients function?
Can you explain to me how this code works?

/actions/burgerBuilder.js

```
export const setIngredients = (ingredients) => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.SET_INGREDIENTS,
    ingredients: ingredients,
  };
};

export const initIngredients = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios
      .get("https://.........json")
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch(setIngredients(response.data));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch(fetchIngredientsFailed());
      });
  };
};
```

/reducers/burgerBuilder.js

```
...
case actionTypes.SET_INGREDIENTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        ingredients: action.ingredients,
        error: false,
      };
...
```

And in the main container, BurgerBuilder.js in the mapDispatchToProps i returned this object

```
onInitIngredients: () => dispatch(burgerBuilderActions.initIngredients()),
```

when i call in above, in the componentDidMount like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.onInitIngredients();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You call it inside the dispatch call `dispatch(setIngredients(response.data));`
This dispatch call receives the object you're returning from setIngredients,

The dispatch call will actually call your reducer with the action returned from setIngredients

Also if you try to call `setIngredients(data)` alone without the dispatch, it never triggers the reducer, therefore it doesn't work